# Why Angular JS input model value does not get updated if i update value of input field using javascript ex: using setTimeout

Tags: angularjs

I have a input field with model named "name" with some initialized value say "James".

And when i console $scope i can see model value as "James".
ie. $scope.name = "James".

But immediate on next statement if i use setTimeout function and update input field value with Say "Marcus" and console $scope again, why i get  $scope.name = "James" only.

I know, i have updated input field value by going out of box than angular and angular is not aware of updation.

So my real question is, Is Angular JS written over Javascript Language? And if yes, why using setTimeout not updated model value in $scope.

Please help me, if i am thinking/question is right or wrong.

Comment: Please provide a plunkr.

Comment: Dont have any issue related to coding my actual problem is : Can I say, Angular JS is not written over Javascript meaning Angular and Javascript are independent of each other. Having a debate over it with my collegue.

Comment: Angular JS implements a lot of functions that JavaScript provides.Take the timeout you mentioned.Angular JS also uses the same as [seen here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) .Based on my work with Angular, I often use a combination of them.

Comment: Additionally, you can't directly console.log $scope.name from the browser dev consoles.Where are you doing console log?

Comment: Thanks @Satej, but my question is why there is a need to have $settimeout function itself in angular, if angular js is javascript based, it should have work with normal setTimeout of Javascript that model updation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how angular handles two way data-binding and the digest loop. If you're interested in knowing all the details of how this works then you can read about it here: https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/

The basic idea is that in angular the digest loop is used to keep track of all the variables you placed in your `$scope`. Whenever a variable changes it sets off the digest loop, in each cycle of the loop the new value of the variable is compared to the old value and updated accordingly until the new value is equal to the old value which ends the loop. That being said this **only works as long as you change your variables within angular's context**, this is especially true for changing variables within callback functions or with jquery. Angular doesn't know that a variable was changed so the digest loop never gets started, you could force it by using [$scope.$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) but some cases should be avoided in general unless there's no angular alternative for it (Which usually isnt the case).

For setTimeout there's an angular alternative which is [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), this has the exact same functionality as setTimeout but it works within angular's context so your variable will be updated.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for the detailed answer but it still leaves with same argument with my collegue, Can i really say that Angular JS is not written over Javascript? or It tempts me to say that Angular Js is not a Javascript Framework??

Comment: ofcourse it's a javascript framework, but it has certain rules(syntax) that you have to follow in order for it work correctly. This is true for any js framework out there. Similar to how in reactjs if you want to update a variable in the view you can't just user `x = newValue` you have to use the setState method.